# Ubuntu 18.04 No Sign-in

Tags: 18.04

Today, I installed Ubuntu 18.04. The installation was just fine: no lags, no errors. Then, I rebooted, and it brought me to the sign-in. As I moved my mouse to the icon for my user, the mouse started lagging. I assumed this was because it just booted up. Then, I typed in my password, and it exited out, straight back to the sign-in screen. I cannot log in! What is going on with the lag and no sign-in?

Thanks!

Comment: Similar issue here.  The usual suspect is the video card driver: what graphic card do you use ? In this case, however, I cannot even access the tty (Ctr+ALT+F2 to F6) ? Can you ?

Comment: @TradDog, I used the GeForce GT 1030. I simply reinstalled later, and it fixed it. Sorry, I should've edited it. What I did was went to ubuntu.com and reinstalled the .iso file. Then, I burned it to a dvd. I booted from that, and it worked just fine this time. Not quite sure what was wrong with the initial dvd, but it worked the second time. Sorry I'm unable to help.